# Update $_SESSION[balance] automatically?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, jquery

I get the value of `$_SESSION[balance]` from a MySQL database on every login. How can I update the value in clients browser without reloading the page every 5 minutes? I think it can possibly be done using AJAX?

Sorry if that's too vague I'm absolutely clueless as to where to start on this.

Comment: how often does `balance` change and what changes it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your're right, you need AJAX for this. easiest way is to use `$.get();` with the [jQuery library](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery#Download_jQuery)

**js/jQuery script**

```
window.setInterval(function() {

    $.get('script.php', function(balance) {
        $('#balance').html(balance); // set the value to the element with the ID balance
    });

}, 60000); // execute every minute
```

in `script.php` you simply query the database for the balance and echo it